# Youtube API : channels.list() returns only account channel, but does not list rest of the channels (i.e brand accounts)

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have a requirement where iam supposed to extract all the possible channels present under a single google account. Now, the first youtube channel i created, is present as a Youtube studio channel, but after this, whichever account i create, it falls into the "Brand Account".
My first channel linked to my account is called "Earth", the second one is "Jupiter" and third one is "Mars". Note that "Jupiter", "Mars" are brand accounts.

Iam using the code this way to extract channel details:

```
SCOPE_CMD_MAPPER = {"upload"     : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
                    "readdata"   : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
                    "search"     : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
                    "update"     : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
                    "resources"  : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner"
}

def get_mychannel_details(client_secrets_file, youtube_access_file):
    youtube = get_authenticated_service("readdata",client_secrets_file)
    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        mine=True
    )
    response = request.execute()
    logger.info("get_mychannel_details", "Youtube", f"{response}")

    return response
```

The response i get is only of "Earth".
I tried to change permissions for both the brand accounts, but nothing seems to be working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite some time, i realised that , with every channel associated with 1 google account, authentication is required. So basically, if you authenticate with your account, an access_token is provided for the first channel of that account. (Ex: Earth --> in my question)

From then on, if you are creating multiple channels, for each channel(brand accounts), you have to authenticate, get the access_token, use that particular access token to get any data related to that channel.
(Ex: access token of "Jupiter" , and access_token of "Mars" are provided separately upon authenticating each of them respectively)

I hope this helps..!